# Standard Actions in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button, action, lightning-record-page

Who can tell me if it is possible to attach standard actions like edit, clone, delete to custom buttons when creating a custom Record Page in LWC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with `lightning/navigation` service.

You're interested in something like this

```
{
       type: 'standard__recordPage',
       attributes: {
           recordId: '001xx000003DGg0AAG',
           objectApiName: 'Account',
           actionName: 'edit'
       }
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-
library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type

This should open a modal with standard action. The downside is that you can't handle response directly